# Logging system interactions as a user vs as a flag

Tags: design, logging

When running a site that has a CRM with a logging facility that logs users interactions (someone changing a name, address or user permission etc), is it better to log system interactions (automated tasks and alike) as a fake user set up as a constant either in a "users" object, or as part of the application settings so you can either do `applicationscope.SystemUser` or `UserObject.getSystemUser()`.

Having talked in work, some colleagues believe it is an abuse of the User database to have a fake user in there to represent the System and believe it better to alter up the database so tables that are affected by such a change carry a `isSystem` flag that would be set to 1 should the system make changes.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the system authorization context *is* the right thing to be associating with the system tasks, but it's not really a user. But spreading lots of “isSystem” magic flags all over the place is just a recipe for getting it wrong (seriously; you're looking at something that will tend to produce errors and in ways that fail in ways that can be really embarrassing for you). We need another way. Fortunately, there is one; it's all really a matter of you having your conceptual class hierarchy wrong.

Right now, you have all users as instances of `UserObject`, and nominate one of them as being special. Well, we want to put the special-ness of the system identity in the class hierarchy (nominating special instances is problematic in itself). We do that by defining a `SystemUser`, which is different in that you create a (singleton?) instance of it and prohibit it from logging in. Subclass it from `UserObject` and you've captured what's going on…

Except… it doesn't sound like a user really, does it? So let's change the class hierarchy. Instead of having `SystemUser` inherit from `UserObject`, let's have a new superclass/interface, `IdentityContext`, and have `SystemIdentityContext` (note the name change; we don't need to pretend that it's a user now) and `UserObject` both inherit from it. You can then make logging in an added feature of `UserObject`, safe in the knowledge that the system can definitely never log in — you're not abusing that humble database of users — and yet you've got an unambiguous notion of identity that clearly marks those system tasks for what they are.

(Whenever you've got a problem where you've got two alternatives that appear to be both equally valid in some way and yet neither is perfect, take a moment to step back and think “Is there another way that I've not spotted yet?” There usually is…)